# Can`t create Python venv using WSL Debian and Python3.10

Tags: python, linux, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-venv

I'm trying to create venv by default command (`python3 --version` is `python 3.10.0`) in Debian WSL:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

And it's shows me the next error:

```
Error: Command '['/.../venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I found the internet advises to install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev python3.10-venv
```

but it`s shows me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.10-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.10-dev'
E: Unable to locate package python3.10-venv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10-venv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.10-venv'
```

Finally, I remember that I already created correct venv in another repo less than month ago and it works fine even now. And thats confused me a lot.

Comment: What is your Debian codename?

Comment: @GAD3R it's Buster

Comment: Try installing `python3-venv` and `python3-dev`, the default python version in buster is 3.7.

Comment: @GAD3R I know that 3.7 is default. but when I installed 3.10 everything was fine in this system. Don't lnow what happened after so it doesn't work now.
Also if I'm trying to create a venv by python3.7 it says that i need to `apt-get install python3-venv` but when i using this command it says `python3-venv is already the newest version`

Answer (score -2):

The reason why it helped was `lsb_release` issue.

The way that worked for me is:

1. Open `/usr/bin/lsb_release` as root or by sudo.
2. Edit first line of file from `# !/usr/bin/python3 -Es` to `# !/usr/bin/python3.10 -Es`.
3. Save file.

And then venv should work fine.

Comment: If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to an answer as an answer...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I dont think that it's duplicate, cause question wasn't same, only answer) So if someone catches same issue, they can find a solution much faster.

Comment: The problem, though, is that there's no obvious correlation between that response and your question; rather than making a link-only answer you should explain what you did and how/why it fixed your issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. I`ve edited my answer. Hope it seems better now.